# Prevent From 2 NotfiyIcons showing when program is open more than once at a time

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem with trying to get 1 NotfiyIcon to show rather than 2, when the application is open twice. An example can be, notepad being open twice (one editing one file, other editing another) Something like that. Is there a way I can have the notfiy icon open only once no matter how many times my application is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form *load* event:

```
If Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName).Length > 1 Then
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
End If
```